# wso2 app factory build

Tags: build, wso2

I wanted to build app factory.
Am I correct that before it I should build:
first need to build orbit, then kernel and finally build the platform.

When it is done I should build AppFactory?

In svn I see https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.2AF/  -this is AppFactory 4.0.2
So I need first build orbit,kernel,platform with the same 4.0.2 version? (first build 4.0.0 and then patch it to 4.0.2)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i was found https://docs.wso2.com/display/AF210/Installing+On-Premise links with instruction.
There is writing to make checkout:
svn co https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/scratch/appfactory_2.0.0/products/appfactory/2.1.0/modules/puppet-manifests  /home/ubuntu/puppetsource/

Does it mean that I don't firstly build orbit, kernel and platform?